# IE9 AngularJs issue:Unable to get value of the property 'nodeName': object is null or undefinedundefined

Tags: angularjs

Getting this error when a page is being loaded with angular js in IE9. No issues with Chrom/FF.

"Unable to get value of the property 'nodeName': object is null or undefinedundefined"

Any pointers would help.I thought this was fixed as part of Angular js 1.0.1 release.

Comment: On the AngularJS Google Group someone posted the [exact same issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/7GgtvagNIZI). There is a link to a GitHub page with some code.

Comment: This is still occurring as of AngularJS 1.2.13 - not version dependent. Invalid markup will likely continue to cause errors, this is not something to be fixed by the framework.

Answer (score 23):

I got this error in IE9 when I accidentally had the following illegal markup.

```
<table>
   <h3>foo</h3>

    ..... blah

</table>
```

Maybe run a html lint to make sure you're not violating any rules like that.

Comment: I ran into this exact problem at work. We had some misplaced text after a <tr> that was not inside a <td>. Invalid markup does indeed seem to be the issue here.

Comment: Yup same was my issue. But Chrome/FF didnt throw any errors like this.

Comment: This error stumped me and the programmer I was pairing with. We had accidentally left some markup in a wrong, invalid section of our HTML.  Thanks @MatthewTschiegg for finding this.

Comment: Likewise, a copy and paste error meant I had a paragraph tag within the close table tag... silently failing and killing IE9 with no errors reported and virtually untestable without visiting every page on the site, damn!

Answer (score 4):

The problem was:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in list">
        <td>{{p.f1}}</td> {{p.f2}}
    </tr>
<table>
```

Remember `<tr>` should contain only `<td>` tag not any another tag or raw text according to the HTML specification. Modern browsers (including IE 10) can deal with that mistake but in IE 9 angular raises an error.

Comment: Indeed. I faced a similar situation a few minutes ago, the error was a bad-formed HTML comment.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you messed up with the syntax inside the

```
<table> <SOMETHING> </table>
```

I suggest you copy the DOM from browser and do a check on the https://validator.w3.org/check . 
Look for errors like : **document type does not allow element "SOMETHING" here; missing one of "TH", "TD" start-tag** .

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on angular-perf.js. If you add an conditional comment to exclude IE, it will work, but you won't be able to use angular-perf in IE.

Answer (score 0):

For me the culprit was a **thead** tag in the table:

```
 <table>
   <thead>bla</thead>
    ...        
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a case of having a table row inside of a div.  I was fine as soon as I removed the intervening div.

```
<table>
  <div>
    <tr></tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me the issue was << before Back hyperlink. I used htmllint and resolved all illegal mark up error except the ones for angular.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because in a `<table>` I had put some `<h3>` not wrapped in `<tr>` and `<td>`, and also, I have some `<br>` and `<br/>` tags, which should better be `<br />`,  for `XHTML`'s sake.