# How to break a <tr ng-repeat> to display a single line based on ng-if?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm iterating over `$scope.days` *array of objects* on my `ng-repeat`. Most of the objects don't have a `message` attribute.

When a `day` have the `message` attribute, I don't want to display all `<td>` colums but, instead, I want to show a single line with that `message`.

This is what I've tried so far. But seems like the `ng-if` is being ignored.

```
  <tr ng-repeat='day in days'>
      <td> {{day.number}} </td>
      <div ng-if='!day.message'>
          <td> {{day.message}}</td>
          <td> {{day.message}}</td>
          <td> {{day.message}}</td>
          <td> {{day.message}}</td>
          <td> {{day.message}}</td>
          <td> {{day.message}}</td>
          <td> {{day.message}}</td>
          <td> {{day.message}}</td>
          <td> {{day.message}}</td>
      </div>

      <div ng-if='day.message'>
          {{day.message}}
      </div>
  </tr>
```

This is a `$scope.days` example:

```
$scope.days = [
  {number: 4},
  {number: 5, message: 'Saturday'},
  {number: 6, message: 'Sunday'},
  {number: 7}
];
```

On the above `$scope.days` example, I don't want the day number 5 and 6 to have 9 `<td>`, I want them just to display the message 'Saturday' and 'Sunday'.

Comment: use data-ng-show=" " instead ng-if, may helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note , i am using a fixed array of '9' here,, but this can also be made a $scope base array limit...

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
 <tr ng-repeat='day in days'>
   <td>{{day.number}}</td>

   <td ng-if="!day.message" ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">&nbsp;</td>

   <td ng-if="day.message" colspan="9"> {{day.message}} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I liked that second ng-repeat, so I won't need to repeat my self in every td. Good answer. Thanks.

Comment: Also in the td ng-repeat, printing of {{day.message}} is useless when we already know !day.message, so you may just place and non-breaking-space with &nbsp; in the empty td cells.

Comment: It was only for debug, haha. Thanks again. I will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You must not put `<div>` as a child of `<tr>` - that's against any HTML spec.

The only reasonable thing there is to put `<td colspan=10>` - single cell that will span all columns.

Comment: Thanks. It worked using an ng-if for every <td>. Is there a DRY way of doing this?

Comment: I wouldn't do it using ng-repeat as this is exactly the case when it is not that good for. Manually populate innerHtml of that table will be the most effective I think.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you need, just use ng-if on the 'message' property:

```
<tr ng-repeat='day in days'>
    <!--display number if no message-->
    <td ng-if="!day.message"> {{day.number}}</td>
    <!--add the td for message if it exists-->
    <td ng-if='day.message'>{{day.message}}</td>
</tr>
```

As @c-smile mentioned, do NOT add div into your table. 
Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118526/ie9-angularjs-issueunable-to-get-value-of-the-property-nodename-object-is-nu/30282831#30282831) for consequence.

Hope it help~

Comment: Thanks. It worked using an ng-if for every <td>. Is there a DRY way of doing this?

Comment: Every td? Per my observation, you only have 2 properties in your day object, right?

Comment: Yes, but I have 10 td. The first one should always be shown. If there is a message, a td with colspan=9 should appear. If dont', 9 different td should appear.

Comment: I see what you mean. @Jas answer make sense. I just don't get it why do you need the {{day.message}} in the ng-if='!day.message" block. It will always be no value. Would it be cleaner to just leave it empty?

Comment: Exactly. It was there to debug. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use something like this:

```
<td> {{ day.message || day.number }}</td>
```

With this, if day.message returns false (null, etc), it will display the second value (day.number).

Another option is:

```
{{ (day.message) ? day.message : day.number }}
```

if (day.message) returns true, then dispay what is after '?', if it is false then use what is after ':'

//EDIT

In response to your message below, you just need to change your div to a td then :)

```
 <tr ng-repeat='day in days'>
      <td> {{day.number}} </td>
      <td ng-if='!day.message'>
          <div> {{day.message}}</div>
          <div> {{day.message}}</div>
          <div> {{day.message}}</div>
          <div> {{day.message}}</div>
          <div> {{day.message}}</div>
          <div> {{day.message}}</div>
          <div> {{day.message}}</div>
          <div> {{day.message}}</div>
          <div> {{day.message}}</div>
      </td>

      <td ng-if='day.message'>
          {{day.message}}
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Matt, day.number should always be displayed. Sorry, I could have explained better.

Comment: Edited to reflect this