# Angular js issue in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer

angular controller is not working while using **ie9 browser** .It's throw below error

**TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'nodeName': object is null or undefinedundefined**

same code working fine (ie>9 , chrome ,firefox);

My js code is

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope){
    alert('sa');
    console.log($scope);
});
```

My Html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
....
...
...
<body id="top" ng-controller="GreetingController">

..
```

And also

Scope variable is undefined while getting scope variable from angularjs

```
var scope = angular.element($("#top")).scope();
```

Thank you

Comment: this error may be because of illegal html markup - check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118526/ie9-angularjs-issueunable-to-get-value-of-the-property-nodename-object-is-nu

Comment: This doesn't answer your main question, but it's worth mentioning - don't use `angular.element().scope()` outside of debug/test code! [It's only available when debug data is turned on, and you ought to turn that off in production, as it gives you a significant performance boost.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data)

Comment: Thank you Divyesh Savaliya ..we migrating old application in angularjs .that html having lot of iilegel html markup...we can't change this..it's impossible..Do u have any other idea's..???@Divyesh Savaliya

Answer (score 2):

your `ng-controller="GreetingController"` while your controller file has a name `Ctrl`apart from this follow the guidelines dictated here for ie. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Another associated link for the same... check your HTML markup. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3172